# Python: convert timestamp to datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have the following dataframe:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=[0])
df['timestamp'] = 1642104862000
df:
    timestamp
0   1642104862000
```

I am applying the following code:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

But the date I am getting is `1970-01-01 00:27:22.104862` which is wrong. The right date is `2022-01-13 20:14:22`.

How can I get the right date?
Thank you

Comment: milliseconds so `unit='ms'`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. It worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the right unit. Try this code:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format=True, unit="ms")
```

Comment: `infer_datetime_format=True` is not needed if you specify a `unit`.